# Openweather extention not working

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension, weather

From yesterday, openweather extention on the top panel does not show the weather. Its shows "Please wait Loading".

I tried to find the solution. There was a post of creating account on openweather website and use API id. I found that it is a subscription base plan. There was a free plan which allows 60 calls free for weather data.

I thought that the extention is open source. And may be I deleted any package that is required to work the extention so I reinstall the OS. But there is no difference of doing that. 
[image]

What could possibly go wrong any guidance?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and the same issue persists with this OS too. I have sent a bug report to the writer from within the extension page. I would respectfully request that this is not closed as it doesn't just relate to pop-os but to the supported versions of Ubuntu too. If/when I get a reply, I will post a solution.

Comment: @User How long you are having the issue?

Comment: Like you, it started just yesterday - 30th May

Comment: I'm having the same issue since yesterday (may 30th).

Comment: @gccallie I'd recommend you to raise a bug report to the developer too as I have done. More reports to them might help get the issue resolved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found a solution on 
[GitLab](https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-openweather/-/issues/272) from @StephGbzh that just worked for me using 20.04. It is most likely an expired CA certificate:

1. check that you target the right expired certificate

   ```
   openssl x509 -issuer -enddate -noout -in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
   ```

   which will produce the following:

   ```
   issuer=C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
   notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
   ```
2. backup

   ```
   cp /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt ~
   ```
3. delete

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
   ```
4. update the system

   ```
   sudo update-ca-certificates
   ```
5. restart gnome shell: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, `r`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Perfect - That worked for me on 18.04 LTS. Thanks! Could the op mark this one as the solution please to allow others to find it easily.

Comment: I think it might help to separate out the two instructions at number 2 to take it in two distinct steps which will help newish users: perhaps 2a. to backup the file then 2b to delete it.

Comment: When I ran update-ca-certificates, the deleted "AddTru..." certificate is not downloaded. Will its absence cause any problems ?

Comment: Thanks man. It worked.

Comment: That certificate is not even downloaded in my directory and after the update it hasn't been downloaded either

Comment: Just upgraded to 20,04. This does not work for me. Weather worked fine on 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

**Another way to fix it without deleting .crt files, or disabling secure http.**

In `terminal`:

Change directory.

```
cd /etc
```

Make a backup of this file.

```
ls -al ca-certificates.conf*
sudo cp ca-certificates.conf ca-certificates.conf.BAK
ls -al ca-certificates.conf*
```

Edit this file.

```
sudo pico ca-certificates.conf
change "AddTrust_External_Root.crt" to "!AddTrust_External_Root.crt"
```

Update certificates.

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
restart gnome shell with ALT+F2, r, ENTER
```

Reference: https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-openweather/-/issues/272

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-openweather/-/issues/272

But for me workaround doesn't work on 20.04 :(

My own workaround in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/openweather-extension@jenslody.de/extension.js`
on 1116 after

```
_httpSession = new Soup.Session();
```

add

```
_httpSession.ssl_strict = false;
```

works fine for me.

Comment: I followed the link from Jens in 18.04 LTS but even after F2 r it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: This solution involves some coding experience which some users might find daunting but the answer provided by Andrew is much easier to follow why is why it gets my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

After so many days of struggling and couldn't find any working solution in the internet, I have done it in my way and it worked. I hope this will work for you too..

Here's what I have done.

sudo nautilus

navigate to /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions on system side

Use ALT and up arrow keys if needed

Permanently delete following folder with shift delete

openweather-extension@jenslody.de

Refresh by doing ALT F2, r Enter

Goto https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/750/openweather/ and install it again

Refresh by doing ALT F2, r Enter